# Integration By Parts Problem

Tags: calculus, integration

I am stuck on the following problem.

$$\int\frac{r^3}{\sqrt{4+r^2}} dr$$ 
Using Integreation by parts with $u = r^2$

I am not allowed to use a different $u$.

This is my work so far:

$$u = r^2 \rightarrow du = 2rdr$$

$$dv = (4+u^2)^{-1/2} \rightarrow v = ?$$

I am not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try using some trig sub

Comment: should work out well if you factor a 2 out of the square root because you'll have sqrt(1+r^2/4)

Comment: I can't use any other method except IBP with u = r^2 unfortunately.

Comment: Note that, $ dv = r(4+r^2)^{-1/2} $ which is easy to integrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using $u=r^2$, then it looks like we should have $dv=\frac{r\,dr}{\sqrt{4+r^2}}$. That can be integrated by ordinary substitution, and we see that $v=\sqrt{4+r^2}$. Now you can apply the integration by parts formula to obtain

$\displaystyle{\int} r^2 \frac{r\,dr}{\sqrt{4+r^2}} = r^2\sqrt{4+r^2} - \displaystyle{\int} 2r\sqrt{4+r^2}dr$

This second integral can be completed by ordinary substitution, too.

Does that give you a push in the right direction?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. I will select your answer as correct as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Clever and nicely different way of doing the question without doing a substitution. The second integration arising from the 'by parts' can be done simply by inspection as it's a "chain rule backwards". (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=r^2$. Then as you have done, we have $du=2rdr$. Hence, we have 
$$\int\frac{r^3}{\sqrt{4+r^2}} dr=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{r^2 \cdot 2rdr}{\sqrt{4+r^2}} 
=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{u du}{\sqrt{4+u}}.$$
I leave it to you from here.

Answer (score 1):

without integration by parts : set $r^2+4=u^2$ then $2rdr=2udu$ and $r^2=u^2-4$ so it follows that $$\int \frac{r^2}{\sqrt{r^2+4}}dr=\int\frac{(u^2-4)udu}{u}=\frac{u^3}{3}-4u+c.$$
so changing the variable u with $\sqrt{r^2+4}$ you obtain $$\frac{(r^2+4)^{3/2}}{3}-4\sqrt{r^2+4}+c.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $r=2\sinh x$ then $dr=2\cosh x \,dx$ and $\sqrt{4+r^2}=2\cosh x$ so

$$\int\frac{r^3}{\sqrt{4+r^2}} dr=8\int\sinh^3 x\,dx=8\int\cosh^2x\sinh x\,dx-8\int\sinh x\,dx\\=\frac 8 3\cosh^3 x-8\cosh x+C$$